# Clocking block input signal can not be driven

Tags: system-verilog, verification

Clocking block input signal `data_rvalid_i` can not be driven.

CB_CODE:

```
  default clocking response_driver_cb @(posedge clk);    

    input   reset;               
    output  data_req_o;
    input   data_gnt_i;
    output  data_addr_o;
    output  data_we_o;
    output  data_be_o;
    input   data_rvalid_i;
    output  data_wdata_o;
    input   data_rdata_i;
    input   data_err_i;    
  endclocking
```

Driver Patch Code:

```
  task reset_signals();

    `DRIVER_IF.data_rvalid_i  <= 1'b0;
    `DRIVER_IF.data_gnt_i     <= 1'b0;
    `DRIVER_IF.data_rdata_i   <= 'b0;
    `DRIVER_IF.data_err_i     <= 1'b0;
  endtask : reset_signals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clocking block inputs are read-only; You cannot drive them.

Ether remove the driving statement, or change the clocking block direction of that signal to `output` ot `inout`.